# How to detect "OutOfMemory" in UWP or UWP equivalent for "didRecieveMemoryWarning" in ios

Tags: c#, uwp, out-of-memory, didreceivememorywarning

Is there any equivalent in UWP app for "didRecieveMemoryWarning" of ios.

I would like to detect SystemOutOfMemory in UWP application , before it throws any error.

Thanks in advance.

Noorul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , we need to use `MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageIncreased` event, thanks to @Faywang - MSFT for the answer , but we need to do little more work.

This `MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageIncreased` will be called even while app launch . I am bit confused of this behavior, finally found that we need to check for memory usage inside that event.

here is the exact code, which i used

```
private void MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased(object sender, object e)
{
    // Obtain the current usage level
    var level = MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLevel;

    // Check the usage level to determine whether reducing memory is necessary.
    // Memory usage may have been fine when initially entering the background but
    // the app may have increased its memory usage since then and will need to trim back.
    if (level == AppMemoryUsageLevel.OverLimit || level == AppMemoryUsageLevel.High)
    {
        HandleOutOfMemory();
    }
}
```

Here is the thread in which I got this answer.
[How to detect "OutOfMemory" warning in UWP app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afd23665-ce6b-4df2-8945-016662bc7d65/how-to-detect-quotoutofmemoryquot-warning-in-uwp-app?forum=powermanagement)

Answer (score 2):

In UWP, you can use [AppMemoryUsageIncreased](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager) event to detect, it is raised when the app's memory consumption has increased to a higher value in the AppMemoryUsageLevel enumeration.

```
Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageIncreased += MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased;

private void MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased(object sender, object e)
{
     // do something            
}
```

Comment: is there anyway , we can test it while debug !

Comment: You could add some operations that consume memory to test it.